# A question about tensor product over rings .

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A,B,C$ be three rings such that $f:A\to B$ and $g:A\to C$ are ring homomorphisms.

How is $B\otimes_A C$ defined? I am especially worried about how $b\otimes_A tc$ is defined, where $t$ is a scalar. Does $t$ belong to $f(B)$, or can it be any element in ring $C$? How do we write it as $r(b\otimes_A c)$ or $(sb)\otimes_A c$ for suitable $r,s$?

Comment: I find the question a little bit confusing. In your setup $B$ and $C$ have the structure of $A$-modules, and then the usual definition of tensor product of modules applies. (I'm assuming the rings are commutative; that does not appear to be the issue here.) What is a "scalar"? Did you read this expression somewhere?

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh- If $M$ and $N$ are $A$-modules, we know that $m\otimes an=am\otimes n=a(m\otimes n)$. I refer to $a$ as the scalar.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is (here I assume everthing is commutative for simplicity)
$$
a(b\otimes c):=(f(a)b) \otimes c = b\otimes (g(a)c) \qquad a\in A, b\in B, c\in C
$$
The the funny part: usually $f,g$ are not mentioned, they are dropped from the notation, so you might read
$$
a(b\otimes c):=(ab) \otimes c = b\otimes (ac) \qquad a\in A, b\in B, c\in C
$$
where you have to insert $f,g$ in your mind :-)

As a set, this is just the tensor product of $A$ modules. Note that 
$$
A \times B \rightarrow B \qquad (a,b)\mapsto f(a)b
$$
gives $B$ the structure of an $A$-module (usually denoted $_AB$)

Comment: My question is: what if you start from $b\otimes ac$? Remember that $g$ need not be an isomorphism.

Comment: makes no sense. $g$ is just a ring homomorphism, and $ac$ is totally meaningless, usually one defines $ac:=g(a)c$

Comment: I meant $g(a)c$ itself. You'd mentioned in your answer that $g(a)c$ is often written as just $ac$.

Comment: $g(a)c$ is just the product of two poor elements of the ring $C$

Answer (score 0):

$B\otimes_A C$ is defined as the quotient of the free abelian group generated by symbols $b\otimes c$, by the subgroup generated by:

$$ bf(a)\otimes c - b \otimes g(a) c,$$
$$ (b+b')\otimes c - b\otimes c - b'\otimes c, $$
$$ b\otimes (c+c') - b\otimes c - b\otimes c',$$

for all $a \in A, b,b'\in B$, and $c,c'\in C$. Then by the symbol $b\otimes c$ we mean its image in this quotient, where now we have forced the following relations to hold:

$$ bf(a)\otimes c = b\otimes g(a) c,$$
$$ (b+b')\otimes c = b\otimes c + b'\otimes c,$$
$$ b \otimes (c+c') = b\otimes c + b\otimes c'.$$

This is how $B\otimes_A C$ is defined.

Now about your other questions. You mention $b\otimes tc$ and that $t$ is a scalar, which is a bit unclear. Also $f(B)$ makes no sense, because $B$ is the codomain of $f$.

The expression $b\otimes tc$ can make sense for any $t\in C$, simply because $C$ is a ring and we can multiply elements of $C$ in it, so that $tc\in C$ and therefore $b\otimes tc$ is just one of the generators of $B\otimes_A C$. But if $t$ is not of the form $g(a)$, there is no guarantee that we can write it as $sb\otimes c$. If you want, the'scalars' are the images of elements in $A$.

Now if $t = g(a)$, then $b\otimes tc = b \otimes g(a)c = bf(a)\otimes c$.

Notice that I put $f(a)$ to the right of $b$ in $bf(a)\otimes c$. This is how you define the tensor product in general without assuming the rings involved are commutative. If these rings are all commutative, there's no harm in putting $f(a)$ to the left of $b$, so that $b\otimes tc = (sb)\otimes c$ where $s=f(a)$ in that case.

In the non-commutative case $B\otimes_A C$ is not necessarily an $A$-module, so $r(b\otimes c)$ doesn't make sense in general. Notice that for example $B\otimes_A C$ was the quotient of a free abelian group, not a free $A$-module. However, again if the rings are commutative, $B\otimes_A C$ automatically becomes an $A$-module, so that you can *define* $a(b\otimes c)$ to be $bf(a)\otimes c$, or equivalently $b \otimes g(a)c$.